# Page counter for HTML Renderer for PDF using PDFSharp

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf, pdfsharp

I would like to put the page number of each page of a pdf file generated by **HTML Renderer for PDF using PDFSharp** which is an amazing plugin using **PDFSharp** and giving the possibility to render a pdf file from html string, moreover it supports CSS 2 to style the generated pdf.

Thanks to this [pull request](https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer/pull/41), which is available in the beta version, it is possible to have a proper paging with elements not being cut when they are *taller* than the page format.

I tried using this in the css:

```
.footer:after
{
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}
```

with no success (the footer being in a fixed position). I would like to know if someone achieved a proper page count with this plugin or if someone knew another way.

I already tried to simulate the pages count the document would take but the styling in browser is quite different from the generated pdf file (lines height, margins management, etc).